# Como obter a lista de compartilhamentos de uma publicação no Facebook?

Tags: json, api, facebook

Estou tentando obter a lista de compartilhamentos de uma publicação porém parece que algo está errado;

Quando uso o `1365084196885691/sharedposts`na API do Facebook eu obtenho o seguinte `JSON` :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "story": "Leo Letto shared your photo.",
      "created_time": "2017-03-23T12:22:42+0000",
      "id": "1556800757888356_1901235313444897"
    },
    {
      "story": "Leo Letto shared your photo.",
      "created_time": "2017-03-22T03:38:47+0000",
      "id": "1556800757888356_1900507440184351"
    },
    {
      "story": "BluAnime shared their photo.",
      "created_time": "2017-03-22T03:14:53+0000",
      "id": "418054508255336_1366219626772148"
    },
    {
      "message": "https://www.facebook.com/BluAnime/photos/a.418514544875999.97023.418054508255336/1365084196885691/?type=3&theater",
      "story": "Positive shared your photo.",
      "created_time": "2017-03-21T00:22:36+0000",
      "id": "427369474003437_1476680245739016"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTQ3NjY4MDI0NTczOTAxNg==",
      "before": "MTkwMTIzNTMxMzQ0NDg5Nw=="
    }
  }
}
```

Porém o post em questão tem atualmente 43 Compartilhamentos, por que o facebook não está retornando a lista completa dos usuários que compartilharam?

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre em qualquer API bem modelada, imagine o cenário em que algumas APIs são requisitadas mais de 1 bilhão de vezes por dia (A API do Twitter apenas em 2010 tinha que lidar com **6 bilhões de requisições por dia**): 
Retornar a cada GET apenas **um JSON com uma imensa lista** com todas as informações seria um caos por quantidade do dado transmitidos, consumo de memória etc. seria um sistema bem mais difícil de escalar.

***Paginations e limits***

Paginations é um recurso que evita transmitir todos os dados de uma vez só. Supondo que haja 43 elementos ao total e no seu caso foi retornado 4 compartilhamentos, na "próxima página" haverão mais 4 e assim por diante até terminar. Note que pela documentação da API do Facebook 2.8 junto com o seu objeto é retornado:

```
"paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTM2NjIxOTYyNjc3MjE0OA==",
      "before": "MTMwMTk5MTYzOTg5MDU1OQ=="
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1365084196885691/sharedposts?format=json&access_token=seu_token_gerado"
  }
```

O "next" é a URL para enviar a requisição GET para obter a "próxima página".

É possível adicionar o limite de tamanho da lista de quantidade de compartilhamentos, por exemplo você pode obter 10 itens de uma vez:

```
1365084196885691/sharedposts?limit=10
```

**Note**: Algumas APIs estabelecem um limits máximo, por exemplo 100. Caso você envie um limits igual a 200 continuará obtendo 100 elementos ou pode obter um erro dependendo da modelagem.

***GraphAPI***

O Facebook possui Graph API Explorer, uma maneira fácil de testar a API. Verifique a documentação do Facebook sobre como "navegar" entre as páginas e definir limites.

[Using Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)